# Passing Matrices as params in Launch Files

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to pass the data contained within a matrix as a parameter to several nodes in a launch file. [This link](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists) states how to pass in `std::vector<...>` params for bools, ints, doubles, etc. Is it possible to pass in something like a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` via the launch file?

I'm looking for something similar to [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/206146/arrays-ros-launch-file/): given a launch file

```
<launch>
<node name="..." ...>
     <rosparam param="matrix">
         [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
     </rosparam>
</node>
</launch>
```

I'd like to recover the value of `matrix` within the node by calling something similar to:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
nh.getParam("matrix", matrix);
```

This method didn't work when I tried it though. Is there another way this can be done?

(I'm using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322255/passing-matrices-as-params-in-launch-files/) by [jbu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40947/jbu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Robot localization package is a great example for something like this

you can define your 2d matrix as a param as shown in this example:
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/32896d6d1aaec5a92c3a65e5f16dfc0b859a7d26/params/ukf_template.yaml#L209

you can then parse it back using the example here:
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/32896d6d1aaec5a92c3a65e5f16dfc0b859a7d26/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1556

---

Originally posted by [rumman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26171/rumman/) with karma: 26 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40947/jbu/) on 2019-05-01**:
So essentially this works by reshaping the matrix into a 1D array, passing it in along with the matrix row length, then iterating over the elements to reconstruct each row. That seems like a good alternative.

**Comment by [rumman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26171/rumman/) on 2019-05-01**:
Yes that is correct. Just keep in mind, if all the parameters are not specified with a decimal point, you will have to use stringstream to handle them